# Upload large stream to S3 with aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, node-streams

When I try read data and upload to data stream with aws lambda function, when stream size is 250 mb or 300mb zip file upload to success one minute but stream size is 400 mb or 500 mb  function take timeout and not to make upload

my sample code is

```
    let upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
        partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 2,
        params: {Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME, Key: `${correlationId}.zip`, Body: zipStream}
    });

    upload.on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
        if (evt) {
            console.log('Completed ' + (evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total).toFixed() + '% of upload');
        }
    }).send((error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`error creating stream to s3 ${error.name} ${error.message} ${error.stack}`);
        }
        console.log(`image zip file now sending ${data}`)
    });

    await upload.promise();
```

Comment: Increase the RAM size associated with the Lambda to the max for a test. This will give you a corresponding increase in CPU and other resources, including potentially network. Does this improve things? By the way, this (downloading large files from one place and uploading them to another place) might not be an ideal use case for Lambda.

Comment: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/12/19/serverless_computing_study/ <= this article says, if you have 20 lambda functions, your network bandwidth will be like 28.7 mbps. have a read.

Answer (score 1):

Vpc based lambdas support 15 minutes timeout. The reason it takes time is that the request is going through internet. It should be faster if you create vpc endpoint for S3

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/

Comment: There's no mention of VPC here and the primary use case for VPC endpoints is security (via private networking).

Comment: Yes and also the request doesn't leave AWS network, so obviously you will get improved network latency.

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout for all requests in the AWS SDK is 2 minutes. You can increase the timeout using:

```
AWS.config.httpOptions.timeout = 300000; // or 0 to disable timeout
```

Also make sure to increase the Lambda timeout.

Comment: I try but not work :( , my lamda function execution timeout is 5 min

Comment: When is this timing out? After how many minutes, what error are you getting?

Comment: cloudwatch logs is saying "Task timed out after 300.10 seconds"

Comment: Well, your Lambda is timing out... increase the Lambda timeout. If the script is taking longer than your lambda timeout, there's nothing you can change in the code to fix it, increase the lambda timeout,

Comment: now I increasing to 10 min and retry but why is executing too long only 100 mb comes, 300 mb upload one minute but 500 mb is taking timeout ?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, is impossible to know. Test the code locally, and measure the time. Give us a script to reproduce the error, and I'll be able to help you more.